# Where can I find the explicit grammar for C90 and C99?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I'm looking to write a small C compiler, and I can't seem to find the grammar for C99 anywhere. I've found the C90 and C99 standards document, but I can't find the grammar itself anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Annex A in the C99 standard (as [linked by Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#External_links)) looks awfully like a grammar to me.

As far as I recall, there are some extra-grammatical issues with distinguishing typedef names from other identifiers that mean that one cannot just feed it into yacc and expect it to work, but it's the most authoritative source you'll find.

Comment: Indeed there are.  Typedef names effectively become keywords after they've been defined, but they stop being keywords when they go out of scope.  That means that you need some sort of feedback from the symbol table to the parser, something that (I think) most other languages don't require.  Just one example: you can't parse `sizeof (foo[10])` without knowing whether `foo` is a typedef or not.  (Historically, this is because typedefs were a relatively late addition to the language -- pre-K&R, but after the type system had been defined.)

Comment: ... and even after handling the typedef issue, parsing possibly-abstract declarators is _surprisingly_ complex. As a graduate student, I wrote a C parser for a research project, and as I attempted to figure out how do do it correctly I discovered counterexamples for each and every of the existing implementations I could dig up, including GCC's parser at that time. Not that I can remember any of the counterexamples now, nor other details. They were hairy.

Comment: Well I'll be damned, now I feel dumb. As for the context sensitivity of the grammar, I'm going to go ahead and ignore that for now... I'm not writing a fully featured compiler yet...

Comment: Wikipedia no longer links to the C99 standard.