# Identify arrays using regular expressions using grep in bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I'm trying to write a **bash** script that takes input as C file and uses **grep** and **regular expression** to identify and extract array declarations and definitions to dump it on the terminal.

```
grep "[a-zA-Z][\0-9]" << $filename
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Edit 1:
For example, if I have the following C code:

```
int main( void )
{
           int a[N], b[N], c[N];

           for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
           {
                      a [i] = -i;
                      b[i] = i * i;
            }
}
```

Is there a way I could extract the array declarations and definitions using regular expressions in grep?

Comment: 1. What you're trying to do isn't possible with `grep`.  2. I don't understand what your code has to do with your stated goal. What do you think that regex does?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the text you are looking for?

Comment: Your C code is invalid as you haven't defined `N` anywhere. Leaving us to guess whether it might be a placeholder, a macro, an enumeration constant, anything else, when you are specifically hardcoding your check to allow only one type of array declaration, does not make an answerable question.

Comment: It is a macro. I didn't mention it since all I need is a regular expression that can match an array syntax that is "datatype var_name[size]". You can assume N to be anything. It can even be replaced with a decimal.

Comment: If you're just having difficulty forming a regex, I'd suggest a site like http://regexr.com/.

Comment: Attempting to parse C code with regular expressions is a bad idea in general, except for very limited cases. You're just asking for a huge headache. There are tools out there for parsing C. Worst case, you could use lex/yacc (or similar tools such as bison, ANTLR, etc). The C language standards usually contain a grammar that you could use with such tools. For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7048293/3307686) addresses where to find a grammar for the C99 standard. Better yet, use an existing tried and tested tool. They exist. Just Google it.

Comment: As another sidenote, `<<` is a weird redirection and should probably be just `<`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
for((i=1;i<=$arr;i++))
do
    temp=$( grep -m$i "[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]*\s[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\[[a-zA-Z0-9]*\]" < $filename | tail -n1 )
    echo "$i $temp"
done
```